# Matplotlib - Y-axis not on the same scale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a timeseries with two different line plots on the same y-axis scale.

| Time | speed_mph | max_speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:05:02.639000 | 13.81 | 15 |
| 08:05:03.641000 | 13.92 | 15 |

...

[image: Plot]

The max_speed_mph line should be in the scale of the speed_mph line plot.

Here's my code:

```
plt.plot(df["timestamp"], df["speed_mph"], label="speed_mph")
plt.plot(df["timestamp"], df["max_speed_mph"], label="max_speed_mph")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Speed (mph)")
plt.title("Speed vs Time")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What are the data types of the y-axis data? I'm guessing they're not numeric.

Comment: You're exactly right! Changing the data types to numeric fixed the problem and cleaned up the ticks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The speed_mph and max_speed columns were changed to numeric data types.

Comment: (1) This doesn't provide enough information to be a full answer. (2) When someone figures out your issue in the comments, they are the ones who should write an answer; you shouldn't "steal" their answer. (3) This question is a duplicate anyways, so it should be marked as such. Please delete this answer and mark the question as duplicate.